# Недоступны показы через API Яндекс Метрики

Tags: python, яндекс-метрика

Написала АПИ, всё работает нормально. Но как только хочу получить данные по показам, то вылетает такая ошибка:

> {'errors': [{'error_type': 'invalid_parameter', 'message': "Wrong parameter: 'metric', value: 'ym:s:yanShows', message: partner is not enabled for *номер счётчика*"}], 'code': 400, 'message': "Wrong parameter: 'metric', value: 'ym:s:yanShows', message: partner is not enabled for *номер счётчика***.

Использовала метрику `'ym:s:yanShows'` с группировкой с префиксом **`S`** или те, у которых есть `yan` в название, типа `ym:s:yanUrl`'. На все варианты ошибка. 
Пробовала разные фильтры, добавляла  `direct_client_logins`, токен заведён на акк, у которого есть также полный доступ к директу.

В чём подвох?